# Mouse Arrow moving Slowly Using keyboard Keys

Tags: 12.04, mouse, accessibility

My mouse is not working properly, So I enabled keyboard keys for Moving mouse arrow using

> Universal Access > Pointing and Clicking > Mouse keys "On"

But Mouse Arrow moves very Slow using keyboard Keys. I want to move it in normal way as I move mouse, using keyboard keys(Numlock keys 2,4,6,8). How can I solve this ?

Comment: Confirmed on an Ubuntu 12.10.  Same problem:  the cursor moves extremely slow when using the keyboard keys.  Unfortunately, Fly's post didn't show any improvements.

Comment: I am having this same problem but this fix did not work for me. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust mouse keys in 12.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150290/adjust-mouse-keys-in-12-04)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's more than likely the delay that you have set for they keyboard repeating keys.

1. Go to "System Settings"
2. Click on "Keyboard"
3. Lower the "Delay" slider under "Repeat Keys"
4. Raise the "Speed" slider under "Repeat Keys"

Comment back if this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: This didn't solved it for me. Running 14.04.

Comment: same with 17.04

Comment: Awesome answer! In Ubuntu 20.10 the sliders are located on: "Settings" -> "Accessibility" -> "Repeat Keys".

Comment: This method works even for Windows. Thanks.

Comment: On Ubuntu 23.10 it's located in "Settings">"Accessibility">"Typing">"Repeat Keys"

Answer (score 6):

I use these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install xkbset
xkbset ma 60 10 10 5 2
```

Comment: I don't have a numeric keypad, so I can't test your answer, but `xkbset` seems like a good solution here. It would be great if you could explain a little how to use `xkbset` and how you worked out these settings.

Comment: To partially understand the settings, read the man page for xkbset and: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mouse_keys&oldid=854977590#MouseKeysAccel

Answer (score 5):

**Use gsettings to change the speed parameters keys.**

- **To find these keys I used:**

  ```
  gsettings list-recursively | grep keyboard | grep mouse
  ```

  I found:

  ```
  org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-max-speed 10
  org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-init-delay 300
  org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-accel-time 300
  org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-enable true
  ```
- **To know what each key does I use:**

  ```
  gsettings describe org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-max-speed;
  gsettings describe org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-init-delay;
  gsettings describe org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-accel-time;
  gsettings describe org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-enable;
  ```
- **I performed the following procedure to change these keys:**

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-max-speed 2000;
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-init-delay 20;
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-accel-time 2000;
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-enable true;
  ```

These key values ​​are personal, you must enter the values ​​that are suitable for you.

**The image below shows how to control your cursor:**
[image]

Source: https://www.repairwin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/image-8.png