# Where is the cursor speed for mouse keys configured, under Wayland?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, cursor, accessibility, mouse-keys

I basically want to ask [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251158/where-is-the-cursor-speed-for-mouse-keys-configured), but for Wayland. Under Wayland, the suggested solution using `xkbset` does not work as `XKB not supported for display :0`

On Ubuntu 22.04, I have **Mouse Keys** enabled under **Accessibility** so I can move the mouse cursor via my keyboard. Alas, the cursor moves unbearably slow. This is unaffected by the general mouse speed.

Under Wayland, how can I set the speed of the mouse cursor when using Mouse Keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [dconf editor](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf) (run `dconf-editor` once installed), you'll want to edit the property called `mousekeys-max-speed` located at `org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard`. From there, disable (uncheck) the `Use default value` box, and edit the `Custom value` field. Finally choose the [Apply] button for the new values to take effect.

> BTW, as a bonus, while in the `dconf` editor, search for the term `mousekeys` and you'll see several other properties that you can edit to get the kind of functionality you're looking for.

**Alternatively**, if you don't want to install `dconf-editor` and stick to the CLI, you can use the `gettings` command to do your bidding. For example, to query the current `mousekeys-max-speed` key value, you'd run `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-max-speed,` which should return `10` (the default value). Similarly, you'd use `gsettings set` to set an appropriate value. Additional examples and a more in-depth explanation of the `gsettings` command is available at the [Ubuntu Manpage for gsettings](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/gsettings.1.html).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, of course, search `dconf-editor` before Google! Setting `mousekeys-max-speed = 3000`, `mousekeys-accel-time = 3000` and `mousekeys-init-delay = 0` seems a good start for me.